# python idle offline installer

Tags: 12.04, python, idle-python

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Surprisingly, IDLE is not included by default.
Python is there.
I prefer to download tar.gz or .deb installer for IDLE.
Googled to look for it, but could not find.
Where can I get the installer for IDLE?

Thanks,
Vineet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of IDLE in the repositories in 12.04

For Python 2.7 `sudo apt-get install idle-python2.7`

For Python 3.2 `sudo apt-get install idle-python3.2`

And two In 13.04

For Python 2.7 `sudo apt-get install idle-python2.7`

For Python 3.3 `sudo apt-get install idle-python3.3`

In a terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>